# View pdf in browser without download prompt

Tags: php

firefox prompting to download the PDF file every time but the Chrome is Showing PDF in browser without download prompt, But I need to show PDF in any browser without download prompt, can anyone help me?

**This is the code**

```
$file = 'the_pdf.pdf';


header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

Comment: If the client doesn't have a PDF viewer installed, there is no way for them to view the PDF and the download prompt will show up. Nothing you can do about that

Answer (score 0):

This will be based on plugins.  If the browser does not know how to open the file then it will prompt to download it.

Answer (score 0):

"show PDF in any browser": You can't, since most browser allow to override the inline display of plugins via some setting. My Opera for example always opens PDF-links with a download dialog. A web-developer can't do anything about this. And this is intended.